# Dynamically filtering, sorting, and paging using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Is there a better way (I'm pretty sure there is) to create a stored procedure to do dynamic paging, filtering and sorting than the following code?

I'm actually generating this sproc from a database using a T4 template.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspProductWithPagingSortingFiltering]
(
-- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
@ProductID INT = NULL,
@Name NAME = NULL,
@ProductNumber NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@Color NVARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@StandardCost MONEY = NULL,
@ListPrice MONEY = NULL,
@Size NVARCHAR(5) = NULL,
@Weight DECIMAL = NULL,
@ProductCategoryID INT = NULL,
@ProductModelID INT = NULL,
@SellStartDate DATETIME = NULL,
@SellEndDate DATETIME = NULL,
@DiscontinuedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@ThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY = NULL,
@ThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@rowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
@ModifiedDate DATETIME = NULL,
-- Pagination Parameters
@PageNo INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 25,
-- Sorting Parameters
@SortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
@SortOrder NVARCHAR(4) = 'ASC'
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declaring Local Variables corresponding to parameters for modification
DECLARE
@lProductID INT,
@lName NAME,
@lProductNumber NVARCHAR(25),
@lColor NVARCHAR(15),
@lStandardCost MONEY,
@lListPrice MONEY,
@lSize NVARCHAR(5),
@lWeight DECIMAL,
@lProductCategoryID INT,
@lProductModelID INT,
@lSellStartDate DATETIME,
@lSellEndDate DATETIME,
@lDiscontinuedDate DATETIME,
@lThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY,
@lThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50),
@lrowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@lModifiedDate DATETIME,

@lPageNbr INT,
@lPageSize INT,
@lSortCol NVARCHAR(20),
@lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@lTotalRows INT,
@TotalCount INT

-- Setting Local Variables
SET @lProductID = @ProductID
SET @lName = @Name
SET @lProductNumber = @ProductNumber
SET @lColor = @Color
SET @lStandardCost = @StandardCost
SET @lListPrice = @ListPrice
SET @lSize = @Size
SET @lWeight = @Weight
SET @lProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID
SET @lProductModelID = @ProductModelID
SET @lSellStartDate = @SellStartDate
SET @lSellEndDate = @SellEndDate
SET @lDiscontinuedDate = @DiscontinuedDate
SET @lThumbNailPhoto = @ThumbNailPhoto
SET @lThumbnailPhotoFileName = @ThumbnailPhotoFileName
SET @lrowguid = @rowguid
SET @lModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate

SET @lPageNbr = @PageNo
SET @lPageSize = @PageSize
SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))

SET @lFirstRec = ( @lPageNbr - 1 ) * @lPageSize
SET @lLastRec = ( @lPageNbr * @lPageSize + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1

; WITH ResultsCTE
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Name] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Name] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductNumber] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductNumber] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Color] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Color] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [StandardCost] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [StandardCost] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ListPrice] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ListPrice] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Size] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Size] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Weight] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Weight] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductModelID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductModelID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [SellStartDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [SellStartDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [SellEndDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [SellEndDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [rowguid] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [rowguid] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ModifiedDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ModifiedDate] END DESC
) AS ROWNUM,
Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE
(@lProductID IS NULL OR [ProductID] = @lProductID)
AND
(@lName IS NULL OR [Name] like '%' + @lName + '%')
AND
(@lProductNumber IS NULL OR [ProductNumber] like '%' + @lProductNumber + '%')
AND
(@lColor IS NULL OR [Color] like '%' + @lColor + '%')
AND
(@lStandardCost IS NULL OR [StandardCost] = @lStandardCost)
AND
(@lListPrice IS NULL OR [ListPrice] = @lListPrice)
AND
(@lSize IS NULL OR [Size] like '%' + @lSize + '%')
AND
(@lWeight IS NULL OR [Weight] = @lWeight)
AND
(@lProductCategoryID IS NULL OR [ProductCategoryID] = @lProductCategoryID)
AND
(@lProductModelID IS NULL OR [ProductModelID] = @lProductModelID)
AND
(@lSellStartDate IS NULL OR [SellStartDate] = @lSellStartDate)
AND
(@lSellEndDate IS NULL OR [SellEndDate] = @lSellEndDate)
AND
(@lDiscontinuedDate IS NULL OR [DiscontinuedDate] = @lDiscontinuedDate)
AND
(@lThumbNailPhoto IS NULL OR [ThumbNailPhoto] = @lThumbNailPhoto)
AND
(@lThumbnailPhotoFileName IS NULL OR [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] like '%' + @lThumbnailPhotoFileName + '%')
AND
(@lrowguid IS NULL OR [rowguid] = @lrowguid)
AND
(@lModifiedDate IS NULL OR [ModifiedDate] = @lModifiedDate)
)

SELECT * INTO #Results FROM ResultsCTE

SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM SalesLT.Product)

SELECT
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM #Results AS Results
WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRec AND ROWNUM < @lLastRec
ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC

RETURN @TotalCount

END
GO
```

Comment: What is the primary key on `SalesLT.Product`?

Comment: ProductID is the primary key on SalesLT.Product table.

Comment: @Ovunc similar to this am having more than 20 columns in our table. had you done any further analysis about dynamic query

Answer (score 6):

These are really the only local variables that you need

```
SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))

SET @lFirstRec = ( @lPageNbr - 1 ) * @lPageSize
SET @lLastRec = ( @lPageNbr * @lPageSize + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1
```

and you don't really need some of them

```
SET @SortColumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))
SET @FirstRec = (@PageNo - 1) * @PageSize
SET @LastRec = (@PageNp * @PageSize + 1)
SET @TotalRows = @FirstRec - @LastRec + 1)
```

you should just use the Parameters that are passed in.

I am thinking that you can't assign a different value to a parameter, so the values that you need to change will need a new variable, but if you aren't going to change the value just use the parameter.

---

you should also be consistent in your naming schemes as well.  if you use a Capitalized first letter in your variables, do that with all your variables.